# Customizing Android ListView Items with Custom ArrayAdapter

Tags: android

I've been browsing to the following example:

http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429

It's a Customizing Android `ListView` Items with `Custom ArrayAdapter`.

---

Everything static is working, but I don't get it dynamically:

```
Weather weather_data[] = new Weather[]
    {
        new Weather(R.drawable.weather_cloudy, "Cloudy"),
        new Weather(R.drawable.weather_showers, "Showers"),
        new Weather(R.drawable.weather_snow, "Snow"),
        new Weather(R.drawable.weather_storm, "Storm"),
        new Weather(R.drawable.weather_sunny, "Sunny")
    };
```

---

For dynamically data it says:

```
Weather weather_data[] = youservice.GetWeatherData();
```

---

Can you someone please give an example how to implement the `youservice.GetWeatherData();`

I've tried a lot of things, but don't manage it.

Comment: Its not android issue, but your Java concept issue.

Comment: You should read a Json parser [**tutorial**](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/). `youservice.GetWeatherData();` is simple function return the right format input data for you adapter. In your case, it return an array of `Weather`. The `Dynamic` is far from simple answer. There're too many ways to provide input data.

Answer (score 3):

I just found a way:

```
    Weather weather_data[] = new Weather[6] ;

    for (int  i= 0; i < 6; i++){
       weather_data[i] = new Weather("A","B");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Example is good. When you get your array simply pass it to your custom list view adapter.

```
private ListView mCustomListView;

CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(context, weather_data);
mCustomListView.setAdapter(adapter);
mCustomListView.requestFocus();
```

Adapter will have to do the rest.
If you want an implementation of youservice.GetWeatherData() you need to split your question in smaller chunks. E.g.: - How to create REST Web service, - How to establish http connection and send "get" request, - how to parse response stream??

**Edit 1**

You don't need to replace data in your array, read Json create new array and pass it to the adapter.

```
List<WeatherItem> weatherList = getWeatherFromJson();
weather_data = new Weather[weatherList.size()];
weather_data = weatherList.toArray(weather_data );
```

// and from above

CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(context, weather_data);
   ....

Comment: Tnx for the answer, but I think you don't understand my question.

I need to replace each New Weather(R.drawable.weather_cloudy, "Cloudy") etc. with data I get from the web through Json.

So all the fixed settings must be removed and filled with dynamical content.

Comment: Weather weather_data[] = new Weather[]
{
 here dynamically each new Weather()
}